# Javascript Theme Cookie Issue

Tags: javascript

Having an issue setting a cookie up. The code is near the bottom between the last closing div tag and the closing body tag.

http://pastebin.com/ZvDDE5Qh

Please Help >.<

Comment: Take a look at the [help] and find out how to ask a question properly.

Answer (score 1):

You should extract main problem code on here rather than provide vast code at other site,  Here is your solution.

Please avoid the use of `escape()` function in `SetCookie()`

This should be like

```
document.cookie = cookieName+"="+cookieValue + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();
```

Instead of

```
document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue) + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();
```

Comment: Hello, that did not work :/ the site is up right now. http://divisioncraft.net/

Comment: With above code, setting cookie is fine http://jsfiddle.net/suman_bogati/pLnUG/, there must be other problems.

Comment: Yes that portion of code works fine, ive tested that separatly. its when i add it in with the value selection for the css style that is screws up, but i know not of why it does that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/57Nnc/2/show
http://jsfiddle.net/57Nnc/2/

Those Should help

Comment: Please have a look http://jsfiddle.net/suman_bogati/Rz8xD/ for your solution.